# Get parent directive controller in child directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following directive:

```
angular.module('test').directive('childDirective', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^parentDirective',
        controller: function() {
            // How do I get parentDirective's controller?
        },
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $controller) {
            var data = $controller.parentDirectiveData;
            ....
            ....
        }
    };
}]);
```

In the link function I get $controller dependency that holds a reference to parentDirective's controller. How do I get that reference in childDirective's controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options, you can either put it on the scope, or store it in a variable that the controller can access also:

```
angular.module('test').directive('childDirective', [function() {

    var parentCtrl;

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^parentDirective',
        controller: function() {
            // parentCtrl will be defined after the link function runs.
        },
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $controller) {
            var data = $controller.parentDirectiveData;
            parentCtrl = $controller
        }
    };
}]);
```

**Importantly** please note that the controller function will run **before** the link function, so you can only really use this in async callbacks.

There is no way to inject the instance of the parent's controller into the child controller before this, because it relies on the directives being bound to the scope in order for that hierarchy to be defined.

Comment: I am looking for an "official" answer but this seems like a workaround.

Comment: Note the last paragraph. The controller is like any other controller, you inject references to things into it using angular's dependency injection. How would the injector know which instance of the parent directive's controller to inject (remember there is one per directive instance) if you haven't bound the child directive to a scope yet (happens in the linking function, and **defines** the directive's parent). In other words, the official answer is "do the directive to directive communications in the linking function".

Comment: Got it. The thing is that I am working with controllerAs syntax, and there is no linkAs...

Comment: So you want to be able to access link methods from the markup? I think you will have to put them on the scope, (which is essentially what controllerAs is doing anyway).

Comment: Sure, I hoped to find a way to be able to call ng-click="aCtrl.action()". I guess I'll have to stay with ng-click="action()"

Comment: I was trying to do exactly as per the original Q. Ed's comment above on top of the answer really helped me work out why not to do this.